# python statistics, and histogram

Tags: python, statistics, histogram

I'm having trouble understanding Poisson distribution with python.

I'm trying to figure this

Suppose an instructor offers a class that has on average 100 students per semester. What's the chance that there will be over 110 students in a class? If the school puts an enrollment cap on the class, what should that cap be to ensure that there is less than 5% that the class will be over-subscribed (meaning that the number of students who want to take the course exceeds the enrollment cap)?

Right now my code looks like...

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
mu = 30
#sigma = 1
N=100000
n= np.random.poisson(mu,N)
plt.hist(n,bins=50,density=True)
plt.show()
```

I think I have the graph set up correctly, but unsure about the 5%.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about Python but I'll try to help. Apparently using numpy.random.poisson you are drawing random numbers from the Poisson distribution. There is no need for that - you can use closed forms to describe the density of such a distribution or the distribution function.
I think scipy.stats migth be a good place to search for such a function.

In R the distribution of a possion process can be computed (without importing modules) via the `dpois` function. For values from 0 to 150 events with lambda = 100 it looks like this:

```
plot(0:150, dpois(0:150, 100), type = "h", xlab = "events")
```

[image]

Once you found a suitable Python function for that (an verify by plotting it does the same) you can add all the values from x = 0, 1, 2, .. until the sum is .95.

[image]

95% of this graph are red, which means 5% are black.

Now there is a shortcut for all of that if you can find a quantile function of the poisson distribution. In R my answer to that question would just be

```
qpois(.95, lambda = 100)
```

In any case, there is absolutely no need for a Monte Carlo approach that is computationally expensive and less precise.